# Flutter Multiple combined filter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-web

hey i am new too flutter, i want to create combined filter screen alike in a e commerce app,for example product will have 3 field Brand,price range,size,i want to display data from firebase snapshot by combining, brand ,price and size

````
                stream:
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {

                    final brandss = FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('users')
                        .where('name', isEqualTo: 'zara')
                        .snapshots();


                    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
                      return Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            Map<String, dynamic> userMap =
                                snapshot.data!.docs[index].data()
                                    as Map<String, dynamic>;

                            return ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundImage:
                                    NetworkImage(userMap["profilepic"]),//image
                              ),
                              title: Text(
                                  userMap["brand"] + " (${userMap["price"]})"),
                              subtitle: Text(userMap["email"]),
                              trailing: IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  // Delete
                                },
                                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Text("No data!");
                    }


``` please help me with logic
````

Answer (score 0):

you can try to filter 3 conditions with multiple where

`FirebaseFirestore.instance.Collection('product').where('Brand', isEqualTo:Brand).where('price', isLessThanOrEqualTo: maxPrice).where('price', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: minPrice).where('size',isEqualTo:size)`